# wercker.yml in a subdirectory

Tags: continuous-integration, wercker

having a Bitbucket repository, there is a project in a subdirectory that should be built. I'd like to have the `wercker.yml` in this subdirectory as well.

I tried to add an environment variable `WERCKER_ROOT` to the pipeline containing the subdirectory: `/here-is-werckerfile`, according to [wercker devcenter](http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/environment-variables/available-env-vars.html) which seemed to have no effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't change this environment. It's not used by wrecker, it's only meant to provide a read only information in case you need to know where your code is located.

To answer your question: once again as far as I know you can't use a wercker.yml from a subdirectory as there's no way to set it's location for wercker - it'll already search for it in your repository root.

**edit** however you can change the source dir, as mentioned here: http://old-devcenter.wercker.com/articles/steps/variables.html - with the WERCKER_SOURCE_DIR environment, so you can put your wercker.yml in the repo root but use the sub directory for building.